# First matched keyword in string TSQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a bunch of product description data in an old legacy sales system, which we're trying to run some sales analysis on by making a best guess at model numbers contained within a text description field.

So my sales lines look something like this:

```
LineitemID | Description
----
1 | Sony Headphones for a Sony DHJ232
2 | Sony DHJ232 in blue
3 | SANYO KI8767 with carry case
```

I then have a separate table which contains all the potential product ranges.

```
ProductRange
----
Sony DHJ232
SANYO KI8767
Sony Headphones
```

I want to write a query which will return all my LineItems, with a best guess at which ProductRange they marry up with, which is simple enough with a simple JOIN and LIKE statement, however; The complication arrises as in LineItem #1 where we have two different product ranges mentioned, which would result in multiple matches, one of which would be incorrect.

In this instance where multiple matches are found, I want to assume that the first match in the string is the most correct. i.e. Sony Headphones, not Sony DHJ232.

Can anyone offer some suggestions on the best approach for this?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this. You should order your results with position of substring in the Description field (using [CHARINDEX()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)) and select first (with lowest).

```
SELECT LineitemId,Description,ProductRange

FROM
(
SELECT LineitemId,Description,PR.ProductRange as ProductRange,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LineitemId 
                          ORDER BY CHARINDEX(PR.ProductRange,Description)
                          ) AS RowN

FROM T
JOIN PR on (T.Description LIKE '%'+PR.ProductRange+'%')
) as T1
WHERE RN=1
```

Comment: This looks real good to me! You may want to normalize the legacy data though. From my experiences with legacy data and free text fields there may be instances where there are double spaces and there may be a potential missed match. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH MATCH_START AS
(
    SELECT LI.POS, LI.LINEITEMID, PRODUCT.PRODUCTRANGE, LI.DESCRIPTION 
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LINEITEMID) POS, LINEITEMID, DESCRIPTION FROM LINEITEM) LI 
        JOIN PRODUCT ON LI.DESCRIPTION LIKE PRODUCT.PRODUCTRANGE+'%'
),
MATCH_CONTAINS AS 
(
    SELECT LI.POS, LI.LINEITEMID, PRODUCT.PRODUCTRANGE, LI.DESCRIPTION 
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LINEITEMID) POS, LINEITEMID, DESCRIPTION FROM LINEITEM) LI 
        JOIN PRODUCT ON LI.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%'+PRODUCT.PRODUCTRANGE+'%'
),
MIN_START_POS AS (
    SELECT MIN(POS) AS MIN_POS, PRODUCTRANGE FROM MATCH_START
    GROUP BY PRODUCTRANGE
),
MIN_CONTAIN_POS AS (
    SELECT MIN(POS) AS MIN_POS, PRODUCTRANGE FROM MATCH_CONTAINS
    GROUP BY PRODUCTRANGE
)

SELECT MS.PRODUCTRANGE,MS.DESCRIPTION, MS.LINEITEMID FROM MATCH_START MS
JOIN MIN_START_POS MSP ON MS.POS = MSP.MIN_POS AND MSP.PRODUCTRANGE = MS.PRODUCTRANGE

UNION 

SELECT MC.PRODUCTRANGE, MC.DESCRIPTION, MC.LINEITEMID FROM MATCH_CONTAINS MC
JOIN MIN_CONTAIN_POS MCP ON MC.POS = MCP.MIN_POS AND MCP.PRODUCTRANGE = MC.PRODUCTRANGE
AND MC.PRODUCTRANGE NOT IN (SELECT PRODUCTRANGE FROM MATCH_START)
```

--first match productRange that starts with the word and later match containint ones.

for example with this data:
SELECT * FROM LINEITEM

```
LineItemId  Description
----------- --------------------------------------
1           Sony Headphones for a Sony DHJ232
2           Sony DHJ232 in blue
3           SANYO KI8767 with carry case
4           SANYO KI8767 with carry case 2
5           Sony Headphones for a Sony DHJ232 B
```

SELECT * FROM PRODUCT

```
ProductRange
----------------------
SANYO KI8767
Sony DHJ232
Sony Headphones
```

The result is

```
PRODUCTRANGE      DESCRIPTION                          LINEITEMID
---------------   -------------------------------------  -----------
SANYO KI8767      SANYO KI8767 with carry case            3
Sony DHJ232       Sony  DHJ232 in blue                    2
Sony Headphones   Sony Headphones for a Sony DHJ232       1
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd want to be able to prioritize which "range" was selected based on more than its ordinal position; so I'd implement something like:-

```
create table dbo.Sales (
    LineitemID int identity (1,1) not null primary key,
    [Description] varchar(50)
)
insert into dbo.Sales ([Description]) values ('Sony Headphones for a Sony DHJ232')
insert into dbo.Sales ([Description]) values ('Sony DHJ232 in blue')
insert into dbo.Sales ([Description]) values ('SANYO KI8767 with carry case')
insert into dbo.Sales ([Description]) values ('Sony Headphones for a Sony PS3')

create table dbo.ProductRange (
    ProductRangeId int identity (1,1) not null primary key,
    RangeName varchar(50),
    Significance int
)
insert into dbo.ProductRange (RangeName, Significance) values ('Sony DHJ232', 1)
insert into dbo.ProductRange (RangeName, Significance) values ('SANYO KI8767', 1)
insert into dbo.ProductRange (RangeName, Significance) values ('Sony Headphones', 2)
go
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].GetRange
(
    @description varchar(50)
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

    declare @ProductRangeId int

    select top 1 @ProductRangeId=pr.ProductRangeId
    from dbo.ProductRange pr
    where @description like '%'+pr.RangeName+'%'
    order by pr.Significance

    RETURN @ProductRangeId
END
go
select s.*, dbo.GetRange(s.Description) as RangeId
from dbo.Sales s
```

This would allow the [Significance] column in dbo.[ProductRange] to specify what value was returned if more than one value was a "hit".

The output from this would be:-

```
LineitemID  Description                                        RangeId
----------- -------------------------------------------------- -----------
1           Sony Headphones for a Sony DHJ232                  1
2           Sony DHJ232 in blue                                1
3           SANYO KI8767 with carry case                       2
4           Sony Headphones for a Sony PS3                     3
```

which could easily be JOINed back to dbo.[ProductRange]